# How to use a value which you are getting from a for loop as return value for the same method

Tags: java, for-loop, return-value, return-type

I am trying to create a method which return a int value(in my case locationY is the value which i wanted to return) which i am getting from a variable which is declared and initialized inside a for loop in thge same method. I tried two ways to do so. In my 1st try code i got error which says "**locationY cannot be resolved to a variable**". Then in my 2nd try i tried to return the locationY from inside the for loop. But again got an error which says that "**This method must return a result of type int**". Can anyone please tell me how can i use the varable present inside a for loop to the same method.

1st Try -

```
 public int getvalueY() throws InterruptedException{
  for(int i=0; i<20;i++){
      PointerInfo pointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
      Point point = pointer.getLocation();
      int locationY = (int)point.getY();
      Thread.sleep(2000);
  }
     return locationY;
}
```

2nd Try -

```
 public int getvalueY() throws InterruptedException{
  for(int i=0; i<20;i++){
      PointerInfo pointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
      Point point = pointer.getLocation();
      int locationY = (int)point.getY();
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      return locationY;
   }
 }
```

Comment: What is `locationY`? 
Your methods have to return an integer, but you're not.

Comment: Your second method looks fine.(I mean the syntax)

Comment: Simplest solution.. declare `locationY` outside(at the beginning of) the loop and sue the first case.. BTW you might as well declare `pointer` and `point` outside the loop

Comment: @jhobbie Sir locationY is a int variable which is storing the value of Y axis of a mouse pointer which i am getting from (int)point.getY();

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - No. He has to return an *int* in the second case :P

Comment: In the first one `locationY` is declared *inside* the `for` block, and is not accessible outside of that block. In the second one the compiler assumes there's a way the `for` loop could exit without returning a value because the compiler doesn't do deep inspection of the code, meaning not all paths have a return value.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why have a for loop at all if you're going to return on the first iteration anyway?

Comment: @TheLostMind :) `int locationY = (int)point.getY();`

Comment: You can't have a return statement like that in a for loop. Once it hits the return statement it exits the method, so how would it continue to execute the loop?

Comment: @TheLostMind Sir when i am trying to declare locationY outside the for loop then it only takes the value initialized to it at the time of declaration.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - But he has to return it from outside the loop as well right?. the compiler throws error - *This method must return a result of type int*. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first try, you're declaring `locationY` in the for loop.
So this variable is only known within the loop and is unknown in the line with the return statement.

If you declare & initialize it outside the loop, you can use it in both places (in- and outside the loop:

```
public int getvalueY() throws InterruptedException{
  int locationY = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<20;i++){
      PointerInfo pointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
      Point point = pointer.getLocation();
      locationY = (int)point.getY();
      Thread.sleep(2000);
  }
   return locationY;
}
```

I'd recommend to look up scoping for Java i. e. the visibility of variables in Java.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int getvalueY() throws InterruptedException{
  int locationY=0;
  for(int i=0; i<20;i++){
      PointerInfo pointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
      Point point = pointer.getLocation();
      locationY = (int)point.getY();
      Thread.sleep(2000);
  }
  return locationY;
}
```

This will put `locationY` outside of the scope of the loop, so you can return it at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try#1 : use this

```
public int getvalueY() throws InterruptedException{

 int locationY = 0

 for(int i=0; i<20;i++){
      PointerInfo pointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
      Point point = pointer.getLocation();
      locationY = (int)point.getY();
      Thread.sleep(2000);
  }
     return locationY;
}
```

Try#2 : use this

```
public int getvalueY() throws InterruptedException{


 for(int i=0; i<20;i++){
      PointerInfo pointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
      Point point = pointer.getLocation();
      locationY = (int)point.getY();
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      return locationY;
  }
  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should give a more detailed context as the loop does not do anything in this case. You just return in the very first cycle. The first and the second solution is totally different. In your first solution you will get the mouse position after waiting 20*2000 millisecond + you should declare the variable in the same scope where you use it. While in your second solution you will get it in 2000 milliseconds - so the loop does not have any meaning